# Joining 3 tables Using ID

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to join three tables, all with the same structure. However the ID in question may or may not exist in any of the three tables.

```
TABLE A id name price sales
TABLE B id name price sales
TABLE C id name price sales
```

Each table represents the prices of a product on a given week. So TABLE A is the current week, B last week, and C the week before that.

I would post code, but honestly everything I have hasn't worked at all.

Comment: I will add that I believe I need one table with an ID that could exist in any of the tables. If that is the case, I would select the ID from there and then join the other three tables. Please confirm is that makes sense.

Comment: Did you want a table with records corresponding to all ids that exist in at least one of tables A, B, or C (and NULL for columns where there is no id)?

Comment: You haven't really provided enough information for anybody to understand the question. As @Bohemian points out, the table design is totally unworkable. Is this homework? If so, please add the Homework tag.

Comment: Well the products that sell will change every week. So consider these tables weekly sales logs. I believe that I simply need one table with all of the possible product IDs. I would then join these tables to that. Is that correct?

Comment: Ok so I answered my own question. The key was having 1 table that had any possible ID that would be in the other three. Then join the other 3 to that 1 table.

Basically it was bad database design. Thank you for your help - it helped me clear my mind and see the issue from a wider perspective!

Answer (score 2):

Your database design is questionable. You should have **one** table for sales that has a "date" column, something like this:

```
PRODUCT: id name
SALES: id date product_id price sales
```

If you don't do that, you'll have to flush out all rows of each table every week and load in the next week... crazy.

Beyond that, your question is fairly unclear as to what you want

Answer (score 0):

If what is needed is to select a row matching `wanted_id` from any of tables A, B, or C, then:

```
SELECT * FROM A UNION B UNION C WHERE id=wanted_id;
```